# Jquery appending dynamic Rows loses style when using partial views - MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have a view which displays a list using a partial view.
When the list is displayed it displays just fine. But On click of add  button I am adding dynamic rows which messes up the style. It keeps adding the 4 columns below each other rather than next to them. I am not sure what might be the issue. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/CompanyInfo.js?")@DateTime.Now.ToString()" type="text/javascript"> </script>    
@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveCompanyInfo", "CompanyInfo", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "getcompany" }))
{
<table id="companyInfoDetailsTable" style="border: 0px" class="rounded-corner">
<tr>
<th scope="col" class="rounded-first">@resx.CompanyInfo_EinTin</th>
<th scope="col" class="rounded-q1">@resx.CompanyInfo_AcctNumber</th>
<th scope="col" class="rounded-q1">@resx.CompanyInfo_BizName</th>
<th scope="col" class="rounded-last">&nbsp;</th>
</tr>

@if (Model.Details != null)
{

foreach (var logDetails in Model.Details)
{
Html.RenderPartial("_CompanyInfo", logDetails);
}




}   

</table>
<p><input id="btnAdd" type="button" value="@resx.CompanyInfo_AddMoreItem" /></p>
```

Partial View:_CompanyInfo

```
    @using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("compdetails"))
{
<tr>
<div class="companyRow">
<td> @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.EIN_TIN) </td>
<td> @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.DUNS)</td>
<td> @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.CompanyName)</td>
<td><input id="btnDelete" type="button" value="Delete" /></td>
</div>
</tr>    

}
```

On click of add button I am adding dynamic row using the below script:
    $(document).ready(function () {

```
$("#btnAdd").click(function () {
var action = "/CompanyInfo/Add";
$.ajax({
url: action,
cache: false,
success: function (html) {
$("#companyInfoDetailsTable").append(html);

}
});
return false;
});



$("#btnDelete").live("click", function () {

//$(this).parent().parent().hide
$(this).parents("div.companyRow:first").remove();
return false;
});
```

Sample:

```
<table border="1">
<tr>
<td>Row1</td>
<td>Row2</td>
<td>Row3</td>
<td>Delete</td>
</tr>
<table>

DynamicRow1
DynamicRow2
DynamicRow3
DynamicRow4
    Delete
```

Result from Add Response

```
        <table id="companyInfoDetailsTable" style="border: 0px" class="rounded-corner">
<tbody><tr>
<th scope="col" class="rounded-first">EIN/TIN</th>
<th scope="col" class="rounded-q1">Account Number</th>
<th scope="col" class="rounded-q1">Business Name</th>
<th scope="col" class="rounded-last">&nbsp;</th>
</tr>






<input type="hidden" name="compdetails.index" autocomplete="off" value="502b6140-dce8-4690-8d96-5b02b37957bd">
<tr>
<td> <input id="compdetails_502b6140-dce8-4690-8d96-5b02b37957bd__EIN_TIN" name="compdetails[502b6140-dce8-4690-8d96-5b02b37957bd].EIN_TIN" type="text" value="147852369"> </td>
<td> <input id="compdetails_502b6140-dce8-4690-8d96-5b02b37957bd__DUNS" name="compdetails[502b6140-dce8-4690-8d96-5b02b37957bd].DUNS" type="text" value=""></td>
<td> <input id="compdetails_502b6140-dce8-4690-8d96-5b02b37957bd__CompanyName" name="compdetails[502b6140-dce8-4690-8d96-5b02b37957bd].CompanyName" type="text" value="Duva Inc"></td>
<td><input id="btnDelete" type="button" value="Delete"></td>

</tr>    






<input type="hidden" name="compdetails.index" autocomplete="off" value="86e37493-ae57-4ba4-97df-92437c6eb33f">
<tr>
<td> <input id="compdetails_86e37493-ae57-4ba4-97df-92437c6eb33f__EIN_TIN" name="compdetails[86e37493-ae57-4ba4-97df-92437c6eb33f].EIN_TIN" type="text" value="987456321"> </td>
<td> <input id="compdetails_86e37493-ae57-4ba4-97df-92437c6eb33f__DUNS" name="compdetails[86e37493-ae57-4ba4-97df-92437c6eb33f].DUNS" type="text" value=""></td>
<td> <input id="compdetails_86e37493-ae57-4ba4-97df-92437c6eb33f__CompanyName" name="compdetails[86e37493-ae57-4ba4-97df-92437c6eb33f].CompanyName" type="text" value="Judy LLC"></td>
<td><input id="btnDelete" type="button" value="Delete"></td>

</tr>    


</tbody>




<input type="hidden" name="compdetails.index" autocomplete="off" value="ad5a9c47-8132-4744-809b-3d18cca63966">

<div class="companyRow">
<input id="compdetails_ad5a9c47-8132-4744-809b-3d18cca63966__EIN_TIN" name="compdetails[ad5a9c47-8132-4744-809b-3d18cca63966].EIN_TIN" type="text" value=""> 
<input id="compdetails_ad5a9c47-8132-4744-809b-3d18cca63966__DUNS" name="compdetails[ad5a9c47-8132-4744-809b-3d18cca63966].DUNS" type="text" value="">
<input id="compdetails_ad5a9c47-8132-4744-809b-3d18cca63966__CompanyName" name="compdetails[ad5a9c47-8132-4744-809b-3d18cca63966].CompanyName" type="text" value="">
<input id="btnDelete" type="button" value="Delete">
</div>
</table>
```

Comment: How does the result of `/CompanyInfo/Add` look like?

Comment: public PartialViewResult Add()
 {
 return PartialView("_CompanyInfo", new CompanyInfoDetails());
 }
Thanks

Comment: I hope I have answered your question, it just returns PartialView.

Comment: Here is the result from the response.

Comment: your result is wrong. A table cannot have a div as direct descendant.you should wrap them inside the tr

Comment: Okay let me try that right away.

Comment: Yes change your partial view.

Comment: Changed and I have added my response. Still same issue.

Comment: From FireBug I grabbed the actual HTML and I have added to my main question area. You will see that the dynamic row is not having the tr td tags associated. Thanks.

Comment: Its still messed up. Check your table structure...

Comment: Hmm, I am lost. I updated the partial view to have the div inside the tr tag. I have also updated my code above to reflect this. I know the table is messed but I am not sure what fix would help resolve this.